# Using RESTful XML Web Services API

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, api, rest

I'm new enough to webservices and haven't used many. I need to use one for my latest task. It's an XML Web Services API, but I've no idea how to interface with it. Are there any tutorials/books available on using RESTful XML-based Web Services APIs anywhere? Or could anyone give me some pointers?

I don't really know where to start or what to look for.

Comment: It might be an idea to specify if you are looking to build one or consume one. My answer is for consuming. bAN's answer is for creating one.

Comment: @deanvmc yes! I just see "I want to create one" but the consume version is also possible :-) thanks

Comment: While both correct, the asp.net link led me to this [ASP.NET Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) which is proving useful. :) And thanks for helping me clarify, yes, I'm looking to CONSUME one.

Comment: For anyone coming to this now, [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RESTful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359625846&sr=8-1) on RESTful web services by Leonard Richardson and Sam Ruby has proven very useful for me. Great at explaining everything. It's not .NET focused, but for me it was understanding the principles and concepts that was holding me back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what version of .Net you can use. If 4.0 / 4.5 there is the HttpClient which will do the heavy lifting for you. If lower you need to look at making your own or using something like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Restful Webservices are a surface unto themselves and it is a big topic to be general about. My suggestion is work through the restsharp samples and come back with any specific questions you have as general questions will yeild general answers.

Comment: Hey deanvmc, I'm using 4.5 so the HttpClient is probably what I'll go for. I'll take a look at the RestSharp link you sent me too for guidance and come back if I've more issues. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: That works out pretty darn well deanvmc, thanks very much for the help, and to @bAN too for his links. Still really useful info. Cheers lads.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a REST API,

Here are some links

- [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis)
- [Code project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426769/Creating-a-REST-service-using-ASP-NET-Web-API)
- [another one](http://robbincremers.me/2012/02/16/building-and-consuming-rest-services-with-asp-net-web-api-and-odata-support/)

It is based on ASP.NET MVC framework but the data returned by the controllers are not views but serialized information.

There is A loooooot of tutorials and documentation everywhere on the web.

Comment: Thanks bAN. They look like great starting points! I'll take a look and get back here if I've more questions. Thanks very much! :)